# How to connect to different database according to request in node js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am developing a SaaS application with multiple users. So I need to use appropriate database according to requesting user. Below is my basic database connection.

```
mongoose.connect(databaseLink, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
```

We can use `createConnection` instead of `connect` to connect to multiple database. But for that I need to specify separate models. Here I need to share same model for each databases.

**Edit**

You can assume that required database name will be stored in `req.dbName` object. So when a user make a request from `client1`, `req.dbName` will equals to `client1` and I need to use `client1` database for that particular request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try useDb for switching between different database using the same connection pool

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-useDb

Comment: To use useDb, I need to specify separate models. But here I will use same model for each database and connection should be made at run time.

Comment: @Prana For that you can create several connections. You will need to be careful, as it is possible to create a LOT of connections when doing this. Make sure to call disconnect() when connection are not needed, and also to limit the pool size created by each connection.

Comment: I can create multiple connections with that. But how to use a particular connection when a request has made? (Assume that req.dbName will keep the database name for a request. )

Answer (score 1):

you can simply make an object and store all connection strings there and as per the need you can use the connection string

var connetion_string = {
"user":"mongodb://localhost:27017/usercollection",
"marks":"mongodb://localhost:27017/markscollection"

}

Comment: My needed database will vary depending on the request. Say one user wants to connects from organization1, then I need to connect to that database.